# Why are RDS queries from EC2 to RDS taking around 22ms each, which is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance (medium, us-east-1d), and RDS instance (us-east-1a, db.t2.medium). I have a PHP page with a few dozen queries. Every single query takes consistently about 22 to 23ms. Which is crazy slow, it should take perhaps 1 or 2 ms each (locally each query takes less than 1 ms).

Any thoughts on how to find out why these queries are so slow? The database is fairly small, there are plenty of indexes, that's not the issue. It's RDS somehow being really slow.

Partial list of queries and how slow they are: (check the first one which consistenly takes > 100ms).

[image]

UPDATE

We stopped using RDS and moved the database onto the EC2 instance itself, and now it's blazing fast. I still don't know what happened with the RDS instance, but this fixed it.

[image]

Comment: Probably something to do with one or more of: the query, the schema design, the data size, the RDS instance size, the network, the concurrent load on the EC2 instance or the RDS instance, or your client code. Without enough details on any of these things (except the instance size), we can only guess.

Comment: The only specific thing that comes to mind is that you're using a `t2` instance. These tend to run out of "burst performance credits" pretty quickly, so after a short time the performance grinds to a fraction of what you expect. They're really only useful for occasional light load, like if you use it for testing. If you need consistent performance for production traffic, pay for an `m5`, `r5`, or `c5` instance.

Comment: Queries, schemas, and data size are fine (locally on exactly the same data it runs below 1ms). Load on RDS is minimal.

Comment: I upgraded to from db.t2.micro to db.t2.small, same problem (queries take 22ms each), then upgraded to db.m3.medium, same issue, queries still take 22ms each.

Comment: Added example queries to the post.

Comment: Also, thank you for answers so far!!!

Comment: `t*` instance types of all size have the same behavior with burstable performance. They all suffer during extended periods of high traffic (or even moderate traffic) because they exhaust their burst credits.

Comment: Of course there is probably a need to optimize your queries as well. I believe you that they are too slow. But you haven't shared anything about query EXPLAIN plans, or data size, or tables and indexes, etc. so I can't make any guesses about that.

Comment: As an example, SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID=1, which is taking 100ms on RDS (consistently). The users table has 100 rows. Query takes 0.5ms locally, EXPLAIN: it uses the primary key.

Comment: Have you tried putting your ec2 and RDS in the same availability zone ?

Comment: Please use text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a simple answer, relating to the speed of light...

The "slow" server  (usually 23ms) is hundreds of miles/kms from your client.  The "fast" server (usually 0.5ms) is in the same building as your client.

To further confirm time, run a simple `SELECT 1`, preferably several times.
That should measure *mostly* the lag between client and server.

If the server were on the other side of the globe, the timing, even for `SELECT 1`, would be over 200ms.  The ultimate limit is the speed of light (until the next Einstein figures out that wormholes really exist).

If you are stuck with a long network lag, and you need to avoid it, we can talk about writing a Stored procedure with several queries in it; and then a single cross-network `CALL` to execute it.

Comment: The OP specified that the EC2 instance and RDS instance are in two different availability zones within the same region. So unless there's a severely degraded network link, it should be sub-millisecond latency.